# how to define a function that gets the number of columns in a pandas dataframe that takes the dataframe as the function's parameter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

say I got multiple pandas dataframes and I want to check their number of columns and create a def function that does that, how? Already tried on my own but when I the following code it returns a type error

```
import pandas as pd
    
def load_csv(filename):
        filename = pd.read_csv(filename)
        return filename

def columns_count(f):
    f = load_csv(f)
    columns = f.shape[1]
    return columns
```

Comment: Why are you naming your dataframe filename ? Also your code is very confusing.

Comment: Which line returns the type error?

Answer (score 0):

Code to loop through dataframes and count number of columns

```
def count_num_cols(df):
    return len(df.columns) # or df.shape[1]

list_of_paths = ["C://Users//file.txt", ]

for a_path in list_of_paths:
    df = pd.read_csv(a_path)
    print(count_num_cols(df.shape[1])
```